# Where to put users in a database schema?

Tags: database, schema

This may have been asked, but I didn't see it in another question.

I am new to database schemas, and I am seeking opinions on how to set up users in a schema.  Is it best to allocate a whole new database for users, or create a new table for users?

Answer (score 1):

Data is stored in tables, so your question about whether to create a new table or not is moot... you're going to have to create a new table. It's a question of *where* - in the same DB that the app uses, or a different one.

If users are going to be shared between applications that themselves use different databases, then put them in a separate database where everyone can "see" them. Otherwise, just make another table in your database.